# "Never ask again" checkbox is never shown in Android runtime permission

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

My phone is Nexus6, level 23.

The target sdk version in my app is 22.

I implement marshmallow runtime permission compatible feature in BaseFragment by Fragment in support package.

According to the sdk document, "Never ask again" checkbox will be shown in the permission dialog after denied at the first time. Meanwhile, shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() will return true.

However, I can't see "Never ask again" checkbox in permission dialog no matter how many times I deny the permission, and shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale always return false.

Are there something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there something wrong?

Yes, right here: "The target sdk version in my app is 22."

Your choices are:

1. Use `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or higher, and implement the runtime permissions code (`checkSelfPermission()`, `requestPermissions()`, etc.)
2. Use `targetSdkVersion` of 22 or lower, and do *not* implement the runtime permissions code (`checkSelfPermission()`, `requestPermissions()`, etc.)

The expected results of your combination (`targetSdkVersion` of 22 and trying to use the runtime permissions code) is undocumented AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call requestPermissions() again after denied?
"Never ask again" checkbox will be shown when you call requestPermissions() again after first denied.

Like this:

```
private void checkPermission(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST:
            checkPermission();
            break;
    }
}
```